# javascriptexecutor.executescript is not working on some applications

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on web application which is implemented with angular and react js. In this, I have a scenario to scroll and check whether element is displaying or not.
I have tried all ways like using x,y values, scrollIntoView and all possible ways what I have noticed on different blogs and technical related web pages. But, i an not succeeded in it.

Here, I need some suggestions like what are other approaches we have to scroll webpage other than javascriptexecutor as this is already applied and failed in my case.

As a side note, elements will be loaded dynamically when we scroll the webpage and will not be available in the DOM itself. To get these elements, we have to scroll manually and check it.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you please post your code for your selenium script along with the source HTML for the page?  What language are you using?

Finally, you say "But, i an not succeeded in it."  What does this mean exactly--does the page just never scroll at all?

Comment: Also, if your page is fully Angular it is likely best to use Protractor, an open source wrapper around Selenium that has special logic implemented to make Angular pages easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

I found a root cause why javascriptexecutor is not working on my application. This script will work only on browser (I.e. if browser have scroll bar), but in my application browser does not have a scroll bar instead it has virtual table scroll bar (scroll bar inside application).

Even I found a solution for the same after 2 days of investigation using Keys.PAGE_DOWN/UP inside do while loop.

Thanks for your support.